# Typescript: how to add a call signature to the Mapped Type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a simple function. You know functions in JS are objects? So I also added some properties to it. There are two important details:

- I don't want to `Function.prototype` methods (`call`, `apply` etc.) to display in IntelliSense (IDE autocompletion) popup, so i use `Exclude` built-in type to remove the `Function.prototype` methods.
- I add methods dynamically, so I have to use Mapped Type for the function.

So my code looks like this, and it does not work as desired:

```
type ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<T extends () => any> = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof Function>]: T[K]
}

function someFunc<T extends () => any>(t: T): ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<T> {
    return {} as any
}

someFunc(() => {})() // the methods are excluded, but when calling,
  it fails with "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
  signature. Type 'ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<() => void>' 
  has no compatible call signatures."
```

So how to avoid the last error message? How to add call a signature to the Mapped Type? Please note that the code below will fix the error BUT also will add `Function.prototype` methods, which is not desired:

```
type ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods = {...} & {
    (): any // <- the call signature added, but methods of Function.prototype added as well
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can represent a type with a call signature that does not have the `Function` prototype methods on it.  The only solutions I can think of are workarounds, the simplest of one is probably not to treat a function like an expando object in the first place, but rather use a plain old object and make the function one of its properties.

Comment: Hi, @jcalz! Happy to see *your* answer! Yes, I thought the same, but still asked, just in case. Now I am more confident to use another approach because this one does not work. Thanks!

Comment: But I think this is a limitation of TS, so I've created an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575

Comment: Did you know classes in TS are actually functions and they are also objects? #mindblown

Comment: Classes are not objects, nor they are functions. What was your point? Maybe you wanted to say that I can instantiate classes, well to do this one have to use `new ...` and my task is to call object/function with just `()`